# Every co-finite topology is compact?

Tags: algebraic-topology, compactness

Has trouble understanding finite set while I was solving theorem on topological space  which is

**Every co-finite topology is compact.**
Let (X,T) be topological space.
In co-finite topology X is infinite set. And every open set G of topology is infinite because x-G is finite( as per definition of co-finite topology).

Now since open covering contain open set of topology hence must contain subset of topology T which are infinite.

We know topological space is compact if every open cover of  Set X has finite subcover.

**Does  by finite subcover it means Set of finite number of elements as set which are further containing infinite elements (subsets which are infinite set) as in case of co-finite topology.**

E.g A= {{10,11,12....... Infinity},{2n; n is natural number}, {n+2; n is natural number} }
Here A has three elements( taking them as a1, a2 and a3) and all three are infinite set.
So A must be finite but a1,a2 and a3 are infinite.

Comment: "Finite subcover" means a finite subcollection of the cover. Let $X$ be a space with the cofinite topology; let $\mathcal{A}$ be an open cover of $X$. To show the statement, consider an arbitrary $A_0 \in \mathcal{A}$. Note that $A_0^c = X - A_0$ is finite, so for each element of $A_0^c$, choose an element of the cover containing it. In the end you have a finite subcollection of $\mathcal{A}$ that still covers $X$.

Comment: Any finite space is compact as you can easily check, so the claim is more interesting when $X$ is infinite. In that case, any open set will be infinite. Given the open cover $\mathcal{A}$. a "finite subcover" is a collection $\{A_1, ..., A_n\} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ whose union is $X$. Of course, it's true that each $A_i$ will be an infinite set of points in $X$.

Comment: Please use mathjax. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation. And don't use an abbreviation as "no" for "number"- it will confuse many readers at first glance.